# Issue value of checkbox not affect on model property speakstuff when call action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-7.0

I work on asp.net MVC app . I face issue checkbox value not detected

changing value from true to false or reverse on model property `speakstuff`.

so I need if yes checked then true if no checked then false then affect this value on model property `speakstuff` .

html script represent yes or No check box

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;">

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
                    @Html.Label("Did You Meet/Speak to Staff", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="true" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") />
                        Yes
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="false" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(!Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") />
                        No
                    </div>
                </td>
</table>
```

I access value from form by java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            var ResignationRequester = new Object();
            ResignationRequester.SpeakStuff = document.getElementById("SpeakStuff").value;
            }
            

</script>


 jQuery code for single  check



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
        $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

});

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ApprovalIndex", "Resignation", new { id = Model.RequestNo }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "display:inline;" }))
        {
            

            <a onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;
            margin-left: 1300px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve </a>
            
        }



[HttpPost]
      
        public async Task<ActionResult> ApprovalIndex(ResignationRequester REQ)
        {
        }
```

So How to solve this issue ?

**updated post**

model that represent property SpeakStuff

```
public class ResignationRequester
   {
       [Display(Name = "Employee No : ")]
       [Required]
       public int EmpID { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Request No")]
       public int RequestNo { get; set; }
       public bool SpeakStuff { get; set; }

   }
```

Comment: Isn't it your element name should be REQ_SpeakStuff since you are passing a modal over. Otherwise use Bind[] to bind the element to modal.

Comment: can you write more details if possible please i using asp.net mvc not razor page

Comment: Razor or not it is the same concept. Please include your model or view model so that I could answer it accordingly

Comment: i updated my post with modal so please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a hidden field for SpeakStuff

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.SpeakStuff)
```

Remove The SpeakSuff property in the checkbox

```
<div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="true" class="speak-stuff-checkbox") />
                        Yes
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="false" class="speak-stuff-checkbox") />
                        No
                    </div>
```

Amend your javascript to update the value to the hidden field upon check selection

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
                $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
               var res =  $(this).val();
                $('#Model_SpeakStuff').val($(this).val());

                //alert($('#test').val());
                
            });
        });
```

The speakstuff value is derived from the hidden field.